# Content security policy causes error in Liferay 7 project

Tags: liferay, content-security-policy

As part of new security requirement from the client I have added "Content Security Policy" in my Liferay application:

```
response.setHeader(
    "Content-Security-Policy",
    "default-src 'none'; script-src 'unsafe-inline' *.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' *.googleapis.com;font-src 'self' *.gstatic.com;connect-src ; img-src 'self' data:;base-uri 'none';frame-ancestors 'none';");
```

But I am getting below error

> Refused to load the script 'http://localhost:8080/o/js_loader_modules?t=1536146336645' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-inline' *.googleapis.com".

Local server up and running localhost:8080. How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like CSP blocks your own script from loading and only allows inline `<script>` tags from `googleapis.com`. You should try adding `'self'` to your CSP rules, because it means you can use scripts from your own domain.

`script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.googleapis.com;`

Comment: Thanks for this answer @Klimiuk,but its a liferay project and it has inline as well as external scripts.Any type of configuration available in CSP to accept both 'self' and 'unsafe-inline'?

Comment: Yeah like in my post `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.googleapis.com;` it means you can load scripts from your domain and embeed inline scripts from googleapis.com. Have you tried it and it didn't work?

Comment: I tried it take one src at a time ,either 'self' or "unsafe-inline",see the error  The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: 'self' 'unsafe-inline''.

Comment: This is a really strange behavior. Maybe something is overriding your content policy. If you open in-browser console and check the response headers, is Content-Security-Policy header visible in the same form you have set in your code?